Finding overlap area when using graphical method for convolution of signals

I am given 2 rectangular functions where x(t) is flipped and shifted over h(t). Red is x(t) and blue is h(t).
When t is between 4 and 6 (i.e. 4 < t <= 6), why does the overlap (i.e. output y(t)) equal to 2(t-4)?


Write more. Are you attempting this?

Yes that’s correct

Do you mean $\Pi$ or $\pi$? (I'm looking at your graphs.)

The first one. As I have mentioned in my post, both are rectangular functions.

My mistake then. Thanks. You mean it in this context. My apologies.

Yes, that’s correct

Thanks for clarifying things against my own ignorance. I'm off to bed. So I'll leave this to others rather than make some gross mistake in writing/checking my thoughts. But I may come back to it if no one else bothers over the next day or so. Best wishes in the meantime. :)

Your red plot doesn't match up with the x(t) equation.  It should be shifted to the right by 4.

I think it's always easier to visualize convolving rect functions in discrete time, as long as things line up on integer time points (which this example does).  Convolution is commutative, so you can choose which function to "flip-and-slide" (i.e. the one that gets the "t minus tau").  In this case you chose \$x(t)\$ (the 2nd equation below), which we'll roll with going forward.
$$
y(t) = x(t) \ * \ h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau)h(t-\tau) d \tau \\[20pt]
y(t) = h(t) \ * \ x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(\tau)x(t-\tau) d \tau
$$
The basic concept is for each value of \$t\$ you multiply the height of \$h\$, the height of \$x\$, and the width of \$\tau\$ (the overlap time) all together.
If we start with \$t=0\$ and then increment it, the plots with respect to \$\tau\$ look like this:














Summarized, the results in discrete time are the following and we can plot it as such.
$$
y[t] =
    \begin{cases}
        0, & t \leq 0 \\
        2, & t = 1 \\
        4, & t = 2 \\
        4, & t = 3 \\
        4, & t = 4 \\
        2, & t = 5 \\
        0, & t \geq 6 \\
    \end{cases}
$$


If we draw lines between the points we can get equations for each line and make a continuous time piecewise representation.
$$
y(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        0, & t < 0 \\
        2t, & 0 \leq t < 2 \\
        4, & 2 \leq t < 4 \\
        -2(t-6), & 4 \leq t < 6 \\
        0, & t \geq 6 \\
    \end{cases}
$$



When t is between 4 and 6 (i.e. 4 < t <= 6), why does the overlap
(i.e. output y(t)) equal to 2(t-4)?

A few minutes after posting my answer, I noticed that you have a discrepancy between your equation for \$x(t)\$ and the red plot you showed us.  The above graphical convolution is based on your plot, but your plot is wrong.  \$x(t)\$ should be shifted to the right by 4.  So, we simply need to shift the result to the right by 4 to correct it.  I believe this may be why you had trouble arriving at the correct answer.
$$
y(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        0, & t < 4 \\
        2(t-4), & 4 \leq t < 6 \\
        4, & 6 \leq t < 8 \\
        -2(t-10), & 8 \leq t < 10 \\
        0, & t \geq 10 \\
    \end{cases}
$$


Because that is the property of convolution. The range of the convolution function can be figured out by:
Taking the initial point of range of h(t) and keeping adjacent to the last point of range of x(t).
The complete portion covered by these two ranges placed next to each other is the range of the convolved function.
Note: x-axis is actually t. Please ignore the x.

PS: Hope haven't misinterpreted your question.

I’m not sure what you mean by complete portion. Is it possible to use the functions from my example when explaining?

Sure, let me just whip up an illustration for you. Give me a sec.

Thanks for the illustration. But why when t is in the ranges of 4 and 6, the output is 2(t-4)?

You're right. It shouldn't be 2(t-4) in the interval 4 to 6. It should be 2 at t=6, but not for the said interval. It should actually be a sloped straight line.
